# Is it safe to use a chipped aluminum stock pot?

Tags: batch-sparge, boil-kettle

My 32 qt. aluminum stock pot was just delivered that I was planning to use this weekend. Taking it out of the box and inspecting it, there is a fairly sizable chip on the inside about 3/4 of the way down. The chip is about 1/4 in x 3/8 in. and is chipped deep enough to expose the inner material of the pot. I was planning on using this for my batch sparge water. Do you think it is safe to use? My gut is telling me to send it back, but if I do that I won't be able to brew this weekend. What could be some of the potential negatives from using it as is?

[Winware Professional Weight Aluminum Stock Pot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CHKL3G)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean an enamel pot?

Comment: I am sure. It is a Winware Professional Weight Aluminum Stock pot. It is not enamel coated, just plain aluminum. Is that bad?

Comment: Added link to question for clarity.

Comment: Wouldn't the "inside" material be aluminum too? What's the problem?  I wouldn't keep the chipped pot, but its still aluminum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A chipped aluminum pot will function, but if I just bought it and haven't used it yet I would definitely return it and demand that Amazon pay the shipping.

In the mean time, look into Sam's Club if you know someone with a membership, I got a 24 quart for $30 there.

Comment: I already initiated the return. I do have a sams club membership! Will def check that out.

Answer (score 2):

A chipped aluminum pot will function the same as a non-chipped aluminum pot.
Be sure to keep it as clean as possible. Since you are boiling whatever touches the chip, it really won't matter a whole lot.
Return it if you are super worried about it. Better yet, get a stainless steel pot.